# Method cannot be called on any member of intersection type intersection - Flow|React|Immutable

Tags: javascript, reactjs, debugging, flowtype, immutable.js

Declared props:

```
type IProps = {
  user: ?Map<string, any> & Record<IUser>,
};
```

Assigning variables from props using destructuring:

```
const { user } = this.props;
const { name, surname } = user.toJS();   // <---- flow doesn't like this line
```

`user` variable is typeof Map (immutable.js map). Have to use `.toJS()` to change it into an object. But then the flow error/warning appears:

```
Flow: Call of method .toJS().
Method cannot be called on any member of intersection type intersection.
```

Was trying to handle it myself, failed miserably.

Any help highly appreciated!

Comment: Out of interest... does the code work as expected when you run it?

Answer (score 1):

It was fixed with:

`const { name, surname } = user instanceof Map ? user.toJS() : {};`